# My iPad does not show in the Macbook screen mirror list

Tags: macbook-pro, ipad, airplay, sidecar

I have a Macbook Pro running on macOS Sonoma (Version 14.2.1) and an iPad Pro (5th generation) running on iPadOS (Version 17.2). I can airplay my iPad to Macbook but can not do the reverse. I do not see my iPad in the screen mirror list of my Macbook.

I updated the OS version to the latest for both Macbook and iPad. In addition, I have tried removing restarting both the devices. I also checked that all version of iPad Pro support [Sidecar functionality](https://support.apple.com/en-us/102597). I have same Apple ID signed in both the devices as well.

Nothing is working out so that I can use the Sidecar functionality to mirror my Macbook to iPad.

What am I missing here?